# My customized javascript is not working in Foundationpress

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

Good Day Everyone. I'm using FoundationPress as frontend and Wordpress as backend. I created a very simple plugin to upload image into the homepage. I've no issue with that. I can display them properly in the page I desired. However I wish to use little bit of javascript for the image slideshow.

However I've no clue on where on earth to locate my javascript files. I also noticed that I can't even find a single .js files in Foundationpress header or footer. I did some search but I cant comprehend any.
Below are my script. Please somebody help me on this.Thanks a million.

I need to locate this in header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This one probably before `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="js/jquery.krakatoa.js"></script>

<script>
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('.krakatoa').krakatoa( { 
            width: '1100px', 
            height: '320', 
            autoplay: true, 
            loop: true, 
            delay: 9000, //Slider on hold for 9 sec
            duration: 800, //Slider Transition Timer
            direction: -1, 
            first: 9});
    });
</script
```

This is how I display image retrieved from database:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
         <div class="krakatoa">//'krakatoa' is the class responsible for slideshow animation


 <?php
 global $wpdb;
 $tablename="tbl_banner";
 $retreive_data=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
 $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
 foreach($retreive_data as $data)
 {

    ?>

          <img  src="<?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']."/2014/12/".$data->image_name; ?>">



       </div>
  <?php
 }
 ?>

      </div>
</div>
```

### EDITED PART

I registered my javascripts here but I'm not sure what to do next. I uploaded in the ftp but no effect.Do I have to do anything to make the javascript take effect?

functions.php

```
function register_my_scripts() {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 

  wp_register_script( 'krakatoa', "http://example.com/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress-master/js/jquery.krakatoa.js", array(), false, true );
  wp_register_script( 'my_krakatoa', "http://example.com/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress-master/js/my_krakatoa.js", array(), false, true );

  wp_register_script('main', "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js", array(),false,false);


  wp_enqueue_script(array('krakatoa','my_krakatoa','main'));
}
```

Comment: you're going to have to share a link .. not enough info. here to help you

Comment: @cport1, I read in the wordpress documentation, and edited the functions.php a bit. It would be great if you could help me on that..Pls refer to the edited part.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added the below snippet of code in functions.php and that's all. Its worked.

//my custom function

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {

wp_register_script( 'my_amazing_script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-latest.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script2', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.krakatoa.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script3', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/my_krakatoa.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);

wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script2');
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script3');

}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts');
```

Thanks.